# Primes as the extrema of a functional

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, prime-numbers

I'd like to write down a functional on sequences for which the prime numbers are an extrema.

One generally thinks of the natural numbers first as an ordered set, and then you discover unique factorization. I'd like to go the other way, first writing down factorizations and then attempt to order them.

Let $M = \{p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_n^{a_n}: a_i, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be the free abelian monoid on countably infinitely many symbols. For each sequence $p:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ we obtain a monoid morphism $\phi_p: M \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by replacing each formal $p_k$ by it's weight $p(k)$.

For some $p$, $\phi_p^{-1}(n)$ is infinite. For example, when $p_k = 2$ for all $k$, $\phi_p^{-1}(2) = \{m \in M: deg(m)=\sum_i a_i = 1\}$, so we obtain all degree 1 elements. $\phi_p$ is a bijection only when $p_k=\pi^{-1}(k)$, the $k^{th}$ prime.

Let's define a density for subsets of $M$. For subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, there is the natural density. $M$ is countable, and the map is just the one replacing $p_k$ by the $k^{th}$ prime. However, this feels circular, and the natural density of primes is 0 which doesn't capture the degeneracy in the above example when $p_k=2$ for all $k$.

Instead, let $M_i = \{m \in M: deg(m)=i\}$. $i$-tuples $(n_1,n_2,\ldots, n_i)$ of natural numbers are countable without resorting to the primes. The tuples refer to the indices of $p$. For instance, when $i=2$ we have the degree 2 elements $M_2=\{p_1p_1, p_2p_1, p_1p_2, p_1p_3, p_2p_2, p_3p_1, …\}$. One can use the "zig-zag" ordering and skip repeats such as $p_1p_2=p_2p_1$ to obtain $p_1^2 < p_1p_2 < p_1p_3 < p_2^2 \ldots$. One can use a similar strategy for all $i$.

Let the $d_i$ be the density of a set $A \subset M$ restricted to $M_i$, i.e. $A_i(n) = A \cap \{M_{i1},M_{i2}, … , M_{in}\}$ where $M_{ij}$ is the $j^{th}$ element of $M_i$, $a_i(n) = |A_i(n)|$ and take the limit of $a_i(n)/n$. Let the total density be $d(A) = \sum_i d_i(A)/2^i$.

In the example, $d(\phi(p_k \equiv 2)^{-1}(2)) = d_1(\{m \in M: deg(m) = 1\})/2 = 1/2$.

Define a function which measures how degenerate $\phi_p$ is

$$
f_p(n)=\begin{cases} 
      -d(\phi_p^{-1}(n)) & \#\phi(p)^{-1}(n)=\infty \\
      1/\phi_p^{-1}(n) & \#\phi(p)^{-1}(n) < \infty \\
      0 & \phi_p^{-1}(n) = \{0\} 
   \end{cases}
$$

Let $F(p) = \sum_n f_p(n)/2^n$. $F(p)=1$ iff $\phi_p$ is a bijection. In the above example with $p_k \equiv 2$, $f_p(2^j)=1/2^j$ and 0 otherwise, so $F(p)=-\sum_j 1/(2^{2^j-j}) \approx -.781$.

For $p_k := k$, $\phi_p^{-1}(n)$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as a product, and so finite, and $F(p) \in (0,1)$.

**Question:** Is $F$ continuous when the space of sequences is viewed as a Baire space?

One could imagine allowing $p$ to be real sequences, a TVS, and obtaining some sort of distribution to be integrated over for $F$. I'm really wondering if there's precedent for this type of idea, and if $F$ can be constructed in such a way that functional analysis could be applied.